# HQL removing parenthesis from arithmetic operations

Tags: math, hql, parentheses, operations

Following HQL:

```
"-(a.import + a.bill)"
```

gets translated to following SQL:

```
"-a.import + a.bill"
```

instead of expected:

```
"-(a.import + a.bill)"
```

This makes the operation to calculate a result diferent from what is expected.

The translation has been proved with org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect and with org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect

Hibernate's version is 3.5.1-Final

Does anybody knows why is this happening? is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because of bug [HHH-6714](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6714). Solution is to update Hibernate to newer version. If you have to stick with 3.x, then 3.6.9 or newer. In 4.x any stable release goes, because it was fixed in 4.0.0.CR6.

I tried with 3.6.10 and parentheses remained.

Comment: Thanks!

Did you mean newer when you typed 'never'?